# Why my foreach loop executes in this order?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a Unity3D Game, In this game there is a iMimic like game.

The problem here, is that, all the code works perfectly, but it has a detail on it,
 The game runs in this order:
[image: How it runs]
, (as you can see, all together), but I need it to run like this:
[image]

Maybe this is a detail with the foeach loop?, or with the IEnumerators?

```
 void Randomizer()
    {
        PreList = PreList.OrderBy(C => Rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in PreList)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.ToString());
            if (item == 1)
            {
                StartCoroutine(OneMethod());
            }
            if (item == 2)
            {
                StartCoroutine(TwoMethod());

            }
        if (item == 3)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ThreeMethod());

        }
}
 IEnumerator OneMethod()
 {
    ButtonList.Add(1);
    GameObject.Find("Red").GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.gray;
    //Sound
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    GameObject.Find("Red").GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
    Debug.Log("Everyone");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}
IEnumerator TwoMethod()
{
    ButtonList.Add(2);
    GameObject.Find("Blue").GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.gray;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    GameObject.Find("Blue").GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
    Debug.Log("Everyone");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}
IEnumerator ThreeMethod()
{
    ButtonList.Add(3);
    GameObject.Find("Green").GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.gray;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    GameObject.Find("Green").GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
    Debug.Log("Everyone");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}
```

Comment: imimic is mimicking the original [Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game)) game from 1973 - give it some credit!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each code in the `for` loop to execute one by one, you have to make it wait for the coroutine functions called in that for loop to finish before the next loop. Make the `Randomizer()` function a coroutine too then yield the `OneMethod()`, `TwoMethod()` and `ThreeMethod()` function calls with  `yield return StartCoroutine(YourMEthod()).`

```
IEnumerator Randomizer()
{
    PreList = PreList.OrderBy(C => Rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    foreach (var item in PreList)
    {
        Debug.Log(item.ToString());
        if (item == 1)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(OneMethod());
        }
        if (item == 2)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(TwoMethod());

        }
        if (item == 3)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(ThreeMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you have to change how you're calling `Randomizer()`. It has to change from `Randomizer();` to `StartCoroutine(Randomizer());` because it's now a coroutine function.